# How to stop a gem of previous version from being loaded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a webserver which is a third party so i can only work in my home dir. I have ruby rail installed under webapps. I changed by local environment variable for `PATH` and `GEM_HOME` to point the local installation folder. This was recommended by the web-hosting service (webfaction) and work fine.

Now the problem is that i install haml new version. I can check it as following.

```
[user@abc n2]$ gem list -d haml

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

haml (3.0.23)
    Authors: Nathan Weizenbaum, Chris Eppstein, Hampton Catlin
    Rubyforge: http://rubyforge.org/projects/haml
    Homepage: http://haml-lang.com/
    Installed at: /home/myhome/webapps/mysite/gems

    An elegant, structured XHTML/XML templating engine. Comes with Sass,
    a similar CSS templating engine.
```

But when i do following for some reason `haml-2.2.9` is activated before the new `haml-3.0.23`. I have no access or rights to `haml-2.2.9` it may be install under some root folder on which i don't have access. How can i fix this issue. Remember i have only rights on by home folder and what ever under it. The `haml-2.29` is not locally installed.

```
[user@abc n2]$ rake gems
(in /home/myhome/webapps/mysite/n2)
 - [F] haml
 - [I] eycap
    - [I] capistrano >= 2.2.0
       - [I] net-ssh >= 2.0.14
       - [I] net-sftp >= 2.0.0
          - [I] net-ssh >= 2.0.9
       - [I] net-scp >= 1.0.0
          - [I] net-ssh >= 1.99.1
       - [I] net-ssh-gateway >= 1.0.0
          - [I] net-ssh >= 1.99.1
       - [I] highline
    - [I] hoe >= 1.5.1
       - [I] rubyforge >= 2.0.4
          - [I] json_pure >= 1.1.7
       - [R] rake >= 0.8.7
 - [F] whenever
    - [I] chronic >= 0.2.3
 - [F] rack
 - [F] formtastic
    - [R] activesupport >= 2.3.0
    - [R] actionpack >= 2.3.0
 - [I] hpricot
 - [F] friendly_id
    - [R] activerecord >= 2.2.3
    - [R] activesupport >= 2.2.3
 - [F] will_paginate ~> 2.3.11
 - [I] compass
rake aborted!
can't activate , already activated haml-2.2.9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guy I have found a solution. I commented out `config.gem` from start and instead loaded `compass` which was dependent on `haml-3.0.23` so now it load correctly. I made changes in `/config/envirnoment.rb`

```
  config.gem "compass"
 # config.gem "haml"
  config.gem "eycap"
  config.gem "whenever"
  config.gem "rack"
  config.gem "formtastic"
  config.gem "hpricot"
  config.gem "friendly_id"
  config.gem 'will_paginate', :version => '~> 2.3.11', :source => 'http://gemcutter.org'
 # config.gem "compass"
  config.gem "compass-960-plugin", :lib => 'ninesixty'
```